# Angular demo init throw and error on node 20.6.0?

Tags: node.js

I was creating a test demo env this morning and I get an error on "ng serve",

```
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

TypeError: Cannot redefine property: File
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Carlo\Projects\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Carlo\Projects\test1\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\helpers\config-api.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)

Node.js v20.6.0
```

After change to Node 18.7.1 all works again.
Also to test it you might clean the build cache.

Just let people know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a bug in NodeJs

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/49497

Angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25782